# How to select first row in selenium?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am using selenium to automate my application.

There will be some system generated report on the screen.

It has request id with href link. If I click the request id, i can view the details of the ticket.

I am not sure which request id to use as a LINKTEXT as it is system generated. Can any one help me in this case to click the first record or any record from the list so that i can proceed.

I can take the attribute value and use it in the linkText. But i am not sure is that any simple way other than this.

Thanks

Comment: Could you provide some generated markup?

Comment: you mean the html code.?

Comment: Yes, it could help us provide an answer.

Comment: 30 is the request id.. <A id=ViewGrid_lnk0 onclick="return OpenWindow('requst.aspx', 'ViewGrid', 1);" href="http://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx/Request.aspx#">30</A>  Like wise it has list of ids..

Comment: is the id same or it's different?

Comment: NO it is lnk0, 1, 2,...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have a scenario like the one below and you need to select the first element in the below case 70

**Sample Html**

```
<html>
<body>
<A id=ViewGrid_lnk0 onclick="return OpenWindow('requst.aspx', 'ViewGrid', 1);" href="xx.xxx.xxx.xxx/Request.aspx#">70</A>
<A id=ViewGrid_lnk0 onclick="return OpenWindow('requst.aspx', 'ViewGrid', 1);" href="xx.xxx.xxx.xxx/Request.aspx#">30</A>
<A id=ViewGrid_lnk0 onclick="return OpenWindow('requst.aspx', 'ViewGrid', 1);" href="xx.xxx.xxx.xxx/Request.aspx#">40</A>
<A id=ViewGrid_lnk0 onclick="return OpenWindow('requst.aspx', 'ViewGrid', 1);" href="xx.xxx.xxx.xxx/Request.aspx#">50</A>
<A id=ViewGrid_lnk0 onclick="return OpenWindow('requst.aspx', 'ViewGrid', 1);" href="xx.xxx.xxx.xxx/Request.aspx#">60</A>
</body>
</html>
```

**xpath**

```
//a[contains(@href,'Request.aspx#') and @id='ViewGrid_lnk0']
```

The above xpath will list all the elements with id `ViewGrid_lnk0` and href attribute containing the character sequence (`Request.aspx#`)

**Java code**

```
//store the Webelements in a list
List<WebElement> divs = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[contains(@href,'Request.aspx#') and @id='ViewGrid_lnk0']"));
//click the first element in list           
divs.get(0).click();//in the above case it will select 70
```

You can also click on any element by changing the index in the get(index) or iterate through all elements by using a simple for loop

Hope this helps you.Kindly get back if you have any queries or if i misunderstood your question